# POS For .NET: Failed to set property DeviceEnabled property of MSR

Tags: .net, point-of-sale, opos

POS For .NET:
I am trying to connect MSR with POS for .net but I cant set property DeviceEnabled = true.
It gives me below exception

EDIT:
Unable to enable the device.  See inner exception for details.

{"Access is denied"}

at Microsoft.PointOfService.ExampleServiceObjects.HidReader.HidThread.StartReading()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.ExampleServiceObjects.HidReader.OpenDevice()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.ExampleServiceObjects.ExampleMsr.set_DeviceEnabled(Boolean value)

Comment: You've given us the stack trace of the exception, but not the exception *message*, nor even what *type* of exception. Those could both be quite useful pieces of information.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote wrong hardware id. I wrote HID keyboard simulator. 
Actually it should be  HID devices.
This error only means that your device is still not detected.